# Server Certificate Missing IIS

Tags: iis, windows-server-2019

[IIS Manager Missing Server Certificates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUcPU.png)

I have a server, CPTE230B, which has IIS installed, and IIS Management Tools. I need to add a server certificate from my AD Certificate Server, but that option does not show up in IIS manager. Is there something I'm missing which causes that option to not show up? (To answer a common question, yes, I am clicking on the server level, not the site level.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't see Server Certificates, because for various reasons Microsoft decides that option can only be managed on the server itself and not in any way remotely.

Thus, you have to connect via remote desktop first, and open IIS Manager on that server to change certificate settings, or use other ways (such as PowerShell) to configure certificates.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to check the file:

> C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\administration.config

there should be an entry like this:

```
<add name="Certificates" type="Microsoft.Web.Management.Iis.Certificates.CertificatesModuleProvider, Microsoft.Web.Management.Iis, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

and further down:

```
<add name="Certificates" />
```

If those are not there, you can try to add them (make a backup first).

If that doesn't help or your IIS-Manager breaks, roll-back.

You may also want to compare the file with one on a server that has the certificate icon.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Sadly, I checked and I have both of those entries.