# When Remotely Managing IIS the "Server Certificates" button is missing

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, windows-server-core

This question is very similiar to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/1081679/server-certificate-missing-iis)

In sumary you need local access to the server or RDP into it, but because I'm running a "domained" Server Core how do I install a SSL certificate?

Is it better to install the AD CA role, or is it possible install the certificate locally and how?

Thanks for the help :)

**EDIT**

After a more carefull analysis the CA of my SSL Certificate (ZeroSSL) only a provides a .Zip file, containing 2 .cert and 1 .key files, and Windows requires a .PX12 file certificate, so a conversion is needed, and to do that here's the [link](https://help.zerossl.com/hc/en-us/articles/360058296034-Certificate-Format).

**This question is still opened**

Answer (score 0):

A certificate can be requested and installed on any machine. Then, export it as a `.pfx` file and install it on any other machines you want.

You only need AD CA if you want to issue internal certificates for all users/machines in this domain. If you actually want to use self-signed or certificates issued by external CAs, then AD CA is irrelevant.

Comment: But the problem is that IIS doesn't allow to add certificates directly, and there's literally no direct access to IIS Manager on the local server because it's a Server Core version

Comment: @TheSenate No. You don't have to use IIS Manager to configure certificates for HTTPS sites. Deep down inside, everything is configured via Windows HTTP API, so command line tools like `netsh` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-a-port-with-an-ssl-certificate or related PowerShell cmdlets can be used, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/?view=windowsserver2022-ps. I will suggest PowerShell as it works everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the help those commands did the trick. I have just one more question: When I import the .PX12 to the server it requests a password, that I set during the conversion process (used OpenSSL), it keeps on failing. But when I try it on a Windows 10 machine it works no problems.

Got any clues?